# How to calculate the MLE for transition probabilities of markov chains of higher order?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, markov-process, transition-matrix

my question is: I need to calculate the MLE for the transition probabilities of a Markok chain of order 2 ≤ k < ∞.

I've calculated the MLE for Markov chain of order 1 on a previous exercise; but I don't understand where to start for the higher order.

If someone could help me, I'll be thankful.

Comment: Isn't a higher-order chain the same thing as a Markov chain on ordered sequences of states?